# What's the best way to store URLs, or URL domains, in AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, constants

My AngularJS app makes calls to an API which is currently hosted at one service, but was previously hosted at a different one, and in the near future is likely to be hosted yet somewhere else.

The URL is regularly changing. For example from

```
myfirst.heroku.com/app/user/mike/profile
```

to

```
mysecond.bluemix.com/app/user/mike/profile
```

etc.

Instead of changing the URL in every location everytime, I want to just have to change the part before the `/app...`.

In an Angular App what is the best way to do this?

**NOTE:** Many of the URLs I use throughout the app, are in modules that are added as dependencies to my main app. So `Module1` and `Module2` both use the URL in their controllers and resources and are then included in `MainApp`. So a good solution for me needs to be accessible to all dependee apps. Is that possible.

Comment: Use .value() or .contant() and inject it in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would like to suggest you that you must use angular constant, Its similar to a service but it creates a constant value which can be inject everywhere in our angular project.

This is how we can create constant

**Constant service:**

```
angular.module('AppName')
 .constant('REST_END_POINT', 'https://rest.domain.com/');
```

**Usages in controller:**

```
angular.module('AppName')
 .controller('CTRL_NAME', ['REST_END_POINT', '$scope', function(REST_END_POINT, $scope){
      //your business logic.
]);
```

Comment: If `AppName` has other modules injected into it, can I use the constant `REST_END_POINT` in those modules too?

Comment: If you are working on AppName module as your project and having different set of injected modules than this REST_END_POINT service can be used within the AppName only because REST_END_POINT service is created under AppName module so It can not be access outside. If you really want to use this in different modules than you should create a different module named as RestApp which will have the REST_END_POINT service So finally you can inject RestApp module where ever you want just like other modules.

Comment: What I ended up doing, was, as CrazyGeek described, created a new module, that contained all different types of constants, and injecting it into each module that needs it

Answer (score 0):

I do use request interceptor for this

```
csapp.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', [function () {

        var requestInterceptor = function (config) {

            var prefix = "http://api.example.com";

            if (config.url.indexOf("/api/") !== -1) {
                config.url = prefix + config.url;
            }
       }
}]);
```

configure this intercept in app.config like

```
csapp.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
});
```

now all your api requests would be prefixed with `api.example.com`.

Comment: where is this interceptor added to `$httpProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

$location.host() is the client browser's 'prefix.domain.suffix'
You can inject $location into whatever scope or service.

```
angular.module('app',[]).run(function($rootScope, $location){
  $rootScope.host = $location.host();
})
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/gDgrlwZFyWNKUJgbHHKj?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <i>Host:</i>
    <h1>{{host}}</h1>
    <script>
      angular.module('app',[]).run(function($rootScope, $location){
        $rootScope.host = $location.host();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CrazyGeek answered your question more precisely, I'm just saving you the step of needing to change the host manually.

Comment: THanks for the cool tip. I won't use this solution exactly but good to know about